# How to reduce bottom border length on hover of button?

Tags: html, css

I have a button which displays a bottom border when hovering over it.

[image]

I want to reduce the length of the bottom border using CSS without changing the interactable size of the button. (Imagine the purple border only stretching to the length of the word) My current CSS is:

```css
.storybook-button {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent; 
  border-bottom: 5px solid blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<div class="storybook-button">Button</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `background` instead of border.

```css
.storybook-button {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: transparent; 
  background: linear-gradient(blueviolet 0 0) center bottom / 100% 5px no-repeat;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.storybook-button:hover {
/*        border-width border-height */
  background-size: 50% 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="storybook-button">Button</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it works great, but can you explain to me what the 50% 100% / 100% is doing?

Comment: it's `background-position-x` `background-position-y` / `background-size-x` `background-size-y`. also  now I changed it to `center` `bottom`. they are exactly the same.